# java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.2.4 (port 4040) from /:: (port 57650): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED

Tags: java, sockets, port, econnrefused

I'm trying to make an android chat application on router wifi (As a LAN) via tcp socket.
I am using the ports :
4040 For Text Data
5050 for transfering files

I have coded every thing but I get the Error!

```
java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.2.4 (port 4040) from /:: (port 57650): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
```

I know that means the connection request has been rejected!!

I have a listenning class on the port 4040 :

```
class DataReceive implements Runnable
    {
private ServerSocket server;
private Socket socket;
private DataInputStream din;
private String recData;

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try{
            server = new ServerSocket(4040);
            while (true) {
            socket = server.accept();
            din = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            recData = din.readUTF();
            discuss(recData);
            }
            }catch(Exception e) {}
        }
}
```

And I put a thread and started it.

Is the reason possible to be that ports are opened wrongly on router settings!! (forwarding port)

**Another Question:**
When I get into my (DLink dsl 124) settings  advanced  forwarding ports

I find three fields :
Wlan Port: 4040
LAN port: 4040
LAN IP : ??
What I should put in the last field?

Comment: Why don't you try connecting locally. If that works, then the problem is probably with you networking infrastructure.

Comment: *"Is the reason possible to be that ports are opened wrongly on router settings!! (forwarding port)"* - you need port forwarding inside the same LAN. The server must a) be actually running on the given IP and port and b) the port must be accessible from outside the server system, i.e. no firewall should block anything and c) the router must actually allow communication between devices (most do by default, but some don't when configured in some "guest network" mode or similar).

Comment: @tgdavies how can I connect locally?

Comment: @UIIrich thanks for your explaining but all of these points are done :/

Comment: Run your client connecting to localhost:4040. If that works, then you know your code is OK.

Comment: I did that. My code worked properly when I used 'Localhost'. It seems to because of router :/